# Solving $\sec^2(x)-2\sqrt{2} \sec(x)+2=0$

Tags: trigonometry

What are the values of $x$ in degrees when: 
$$
\sec^2(x)-2\sqrt{2} \sec(x)+2=0
$$
I believe I should use derivatives of $\sec(x)$ but am struggling.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe that before trying to find out what $x$ is, try to find out what $\sec(x)$ might be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

the equation is:

$$
\left(\sec x -\sqrt{2}\right)^2=0
$$

Comment: Therefore sec x =√2 and is +/- 45 degress

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

This is a quadratic, so you can use the substitution $u = \sec x$, which yields

$$u^2-2\sqrt2u+2 = 0$$

which so happens to be a perfect square trinomial which can be factored, yielding

$$(u-\sqrt 2)^2 = 0$$